# Jar runnable eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

This is a tryout app really, nothing big, it has 119 lines of code. I'm just messing with java fx, trying to create a GUI java app runnable. So, in eclipse, right click on my project

```
export > java application > jar runnable isn't working
```

Jar file won't generate and it gives me "No resources selected" and "Can't find main method" error
I've tried the following (none of which worked):

- Checking my Run config
- Making a new Run config
- Checking if it's the correct main (I've got like one file in the app)
- Downgrading Java
- Exporting project as an archive, importing it into a new project as an archive, exporting it as runnable jar
- reloading an unknown number of times
- rebooting the computer
- finally I realized I lack manifest file, so I created one via terminal (didn't work

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: application.Main
```

After I tried all of that I still get the error. Does anyone know why, and could you please help?

Comment: What exactly wrong with a JAR file?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will edit my question. It won't even generate, eclipse just gives me that error.

Comment: Try to do it with a default pack into a JAR file: `export > JAR file > [write path to a destination] > next > next > Main class: [your class] > finish`

Comment: If you want I can issue it as an answer with detailed description

Comment: Please do. And thank you so very much.

Comment: Ok, that worked. What do I do to make it a runnable jar?

Answer (score 2):

1. In a `Package Explorer` right click on a project and selecting `Export...`
2. Among possible options select `Java/JAR file`
3. Here we have big window:

   [image]

Check that right project selected in a left list

Write a path to a destination file (it will be created if not exists) in `JAR file` field ... and click `next`

4. Click `next` again
5. In such window:

[image]

We should select the main class that will be executed in a start of application (You can click `Browse` to make your life easyer). This screen determines whether JAR will be runnable or not (if main class is not set up -> it would be just a library JAR file)

Comment: @SkyAnthrax94 use it)